# Superfish - add menu item programmaticaly or simply use CSS + jQuery - Drupal 7

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I have a menu in Drupal 7. It is multidomain - multilanguage, for which I use the modules i18n and Domain Access + Domain Menu Access modules. I give Drop-down behaviour with Superfish module. However, I need to add some menu items which are dependent on PHP, they are dynamic and from non-Drupal source. Is there a way of adding theme or should I use the following code:

```
$menu_name = variable_get('menu_main_links_source', 'main-menu');
$tree = menu_tree($menu_name);
print drupal_render($tree);
```

In that case, I loose the magic of Superfish module. Could I add some items on the fly without having to render the menu and still use Superfish? Or better I use the above code and finally go through the menu hierarchy and use jQuery + CSS to render the menu? I don't loose the functionality of Drupal, but because it is hard-coded solution I don't think it is adequate.